# How to get register through unique Email ID in JMeter

Tags: csv, jmeter

I am trying to create script in JMeter for Registration page which contains 5 steps process and accepts unique Email ID.

Steps 1:
Asks for unique Email ID

Steps 2:
Contains some fields and "Email" entered in Steps 1 remains auto-filled

Step 3:
Contain some fields and "Email" entered in Steps 1 remains auto-filled

Step 4 and Steps 5
Some fields and "Submit" button

I have recorded a script and want 3 more users to get registered through unique Emails provided via CSV, however, Registration fails.

Error Screenshot:
https://www.cubbyusercontent.com/pli/REGISTER.png/_dd684965d46d45c68bccb2b7008d63c3

Comment: can you show thread group details and testplan details if they are not confidential?. I see Internal server error in your snapshot. did you try to find out the actual cause?

Comment: yes I figured out the root cause.
Suppose the link: www.abc.com
There is "Register" drop down pop up, which asks for unique Email ID, then click on "Next". (URL:www.abc.com remains the same till "Next" button is clicked)
On click of "Next" button, User redirects to Step2 of Registration page as www.abc.com/register

Manually, when User goes to the direct link www.abc.com/register instead of www.abc.com for the very first time, there is a Internal Server Error.

However, there is not such server error when user logs in to the system, logs out and then hits the direct link www.abc.com/register.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have proper correlation logic in place? ASP.NET web applications use at lease VIEWSTATE page level state management mechanism which holds current state of things on client side and needs to be updated each subsequent request. It is usually looks like __VIEWSTATE hidden input, you need to extract it from previous response and add as a parameter to next request elsewise you'll be sitting on the very first page or receive server errors.

Take a look at [ASP.NET Login Testing with JMeter](http://blazemeter.com/blog/aspnet-login-testing-jmeter) post for example simulation of ASP.NET authentication flow. If it doesn't help - get ready to share you request/response details, we are not telepathic enough to tell what's wrong basing on the fact of HTTP 500 error.